# How to update properties of mounted Vue instance?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to bind the properties of a Vue instance that is manually mounted to several DOM elements (mapbox markers, in this case):

```
  const makerContent = Vue.extend(Marker)

  features.forEach(function(feature, index) {
    var parent = document.createElement('div')
        parent.classList.add("mapboxgl-marker")
    var child = document.createElement('div')
        child.classList.add("marker")
    parent.appendChild(child)
     const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(parent)
     .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
     .addTo(self.map)

    new makerContent({
      store: store,
      propsData: {
        feature: feature, 
      }
    }).$mount(child); 
  })
```

Changes to the store (eg: `feature.geometry.coordinates`) do not trigger changes on the Marker component without a reload.

How can I bind the `features` property to each marker, so the markers react to data changes? Probably not the right use of `propsData`. Perhaps a shared Vuex store module? I think I need to track the changes of ES6 map state, which [Vue does not currently support](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2410)

See my [Mappy.vue component on GitHub](https://github.com/edanweis/vue-mappy/blob/master/src/components/Mappy.vue)